# Restore SMS in inbox

Tags: android, sms, android-cursor

I want to restore sms in phone, but code seems to have no effect.

I read sms, and get sms from thread_id number 4, then I want to add sms in this conversation, using those lines :

```
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
initialValues.put("address", "0644552211");
initialValues.put("date", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
initialValues.put("body", "test test");
initialValues.put("type", 1);
initialValues.put("thread_id", 4);
initialValues.put("read", 1);
getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), initialValues);
```

But nothing seems to be inserted.

**EDIT**

`insert(...)` method return that : `content://sms/inbox/0`

Answer (score 1):

Answer found :

`insert(...) method always return : content://sms/inbox/0`

because my app was not **default** sms app !

Comment: so how can we insert to default sms app?

Comment: but still it giving me a resopnse "content://sms/inbox/0" and nothing inserted in Inbox.

Comment: As you said our app should be default app in insert back, if i do so does this sms will shown to inbox also?